# How do I loop through an array passed directly to dust.js?

Tags: javascript, dust.js

Using the dust.js javascript templating engine, I want to pass an array directly:

```
var templateContents; //loaded by require.js
var compiled = dust.compile(templateContents, "viewElements");
dust.loadSource(compiled);
dust.render("viewElements", ["bob", "joe", "sue"], function(err, out){
    $('#view').html(out);
});
```

How do I create a template file to handle an array directly? I've tried a number of things including:

```
{.}<br>
```

and

```
{#.}
 {.}
{/.}
```

But can't seem to reference the array or the elements in it correctly. The first example prints: [object Object]

I could name each array that I pass in, but what I'm trying to avoid having to do that as the arrays are actually coming from backbone collections and it seems like extra work to do so.

Comment: The second one: `{#.}{.}<br>{/.}` seems to work for me.

Comment: @Trevor I just checked again, and I'm getting [object Object] as the output for that code snippet. :(

Comment: I know I can have caching problems with requirejs. Try clearing your cache and make sure its loading the right template.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor I put a longer explanation below.

Comment: For other people using dust/require.js I made a shim to make it easier: https://github.com/wshaver/speck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what was going wrong with one of the things I tried in the original question, but thanks Trevor for pointing this out.

```
dust.render("viewElements", ["bob", "joe", "sue"], function(err, out){
    $('#view').html(out);
});
```

This will work with this:

```
{#.}{.}<br>{/.}
```

If you've got an array of objects:

```
dust.render("viewElements", [{name:"bob"}, {name:"joe"}, {name:"sue"}],
    function(err, out){
        $('#view').html(out);
    });
```

You can render them by referencing the name property on the . element:

```
{#.}{.name}<br>{/.}
```

Or directly:

```
{#.}{name}<br>{/.}
```

Comment: It looks like stackoverflow is treating the # as a comment in that above code. :(

Answer (score 3):

This answer may be too late :)

This code seems to work for me (passed the array as data object to the template while rendering):

```
var compiled = dust.compile("{#data}{.}<br>{/data}", "viewElements");
        dust.loadSource(compiled);
        var arr = ["bob", "joe", "sue"];
        dust.render("viewElements", {"data" : arr}, function(err, out){
            $('#content').html(out);
        });
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I've resorted to doing. I want to avoid having to do this. Thanks though.