# array of json objects in dustjs template format?

Tags: jquery, dust.js

I want to render the json data coming from postgress on webconsole through dustjs. 
but my data is like(without object key)

```
 [
  {
    "a": "123a",
    "b": "fdhd",
  },
  {
    "a": "123a",
    "b": "fdhd",
  }
]
```

so how could I write template for this data in dustjs.
the template which I have written is as follows:

```
{#.}\
<tr>
<td>{a}</td>
<td>{b}</td>
</tr>{~n}\
{:else}\
  <p>Humm...</p>\
{/.}\
```

but it is not going to help me out.
on webconsole it shows no data available in table.
please help me out.. Im new to dust js and ajax query.
I am rendering this data in javascript in this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:1517/abc',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
          dust.render('templatedata', data , function(err, out) {
          document.getElementById('data-from-dust').innerHTML = out;   })
        }
      });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of your data? What happens when you `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, ' '))` before rendering?

With version 2.75 I get exactly the behaviour you are looking for. From node:

```
var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');
var c = dust.compile('{#.} <tr> <td>{a}</td> <td>{b}</td> </tr>{~n} {:else}   <p>Humm...</p> {/.}', 'viewer');
dust.loadSource(c);
dust.render('viewer', [{a:'bob', b:'carol'},{a:'ted', b:'alice'}], function(err, out){ console.log(out)});
```

prints

```
<tr> <td>bob</td> <td>carol</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>ted</td> <td>alice</td> </tr>
```

This question: [How do I loop through an array passed directly to dust.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110049/how-do-i-loop-through-an-array-passed-directly-to-dust-js) suggests {.a} should also work but that may be dependent on your version.